# Playframework2 like reverse routing in spring

Tags: spring, routes, reverse, thymeleaf

Can Anyone can advice me routing mechanism in spring.

I use thymeleaf for my view and I would like to use class names and method names for my url in views- just like in playframework.

But I like in spring that I define url before the controller method declaration.

Whaitting for Your sugestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 4.1, Spring Framework provides a way to generate routes to resources from templates (i.e. reverse routing in views).

You can check [the reference documentation on the subject](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-links-to-controllers-from-views), but it's basically using auto-generated named routes for that.

I don't know if Thymeleaf supports this in its standard dialect, but [you could quite easily extend it](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/extendingthymeleaf.html#scenario-1-adding-features-to-the-standard-dialects); if not, this is probably a feature that could be contributed to the Thymeleaf project.

Let's say you have a MyUserController like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyResourceController {

  @RequestMapping("/user/{name}")
  public String showUser(String name, Model model) {

    ...
    return "show";
  }
}
```

With such a dialect, you could then refer to an action like this:

```
<a th:uri="mvcUrl('MRC#ShowUser').buildAndExpand('bob')">Show user Bob</a>
<!-- will generate "/user/bob" -->
```

Comment: Looks promising. When I am done with thymeleaf template mechanism I will look at it. Thanks

Comment: I've raised an issue to ask thymeleaf maintainers about this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/70

Comment: Thanks Man. I've figure out the closest solution which is:https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router
But instead of using one dedicated file f.e. `routes.conf` I would like to use spring mvc annotations like: `@RequestMapping(value="/main_page", method=RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: This project is quite nice, but it won't support all Spring MVC features: content negotiation, etc. Note that this project is totally incompatible with `@RequestMapping` annotations; that's the core of it. If you're comfortable with `@RequestMapping` annotations, I'd suggest you to stick with it. Disclaimer: I'm the main contributor of this project.

Comment: So You suggest the only way to achieve this is to write my own implementation of reverse routing (with java reflection I suppose)?

Comment: No, if you look at the first link in my answer, you'll see that it's already available in Spring with MvcUriComponentsBuilder; I just don't know if thymeleaf can use this OOTB. Also, springmvc-router works pretty well for this as well. My only advice is: stick with what you're comfortable with if you can (Spring MVC + Thymeleaf) before rewriting your whole routing metadata in your app.

Comment: MvcUriComponentsBuilder dosnt work in thymeleaf. This is new application, so I dont have to rewrite much. I've just cant choose...

Comment: mvcUrl() will be supported in next realese of thymeleaf. I think that will resolve my problem. Issue: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/70
I think we can close. Thanks Brian Clozel

Answer (score 1):

This is the general flow in spring framework.

1. Whenever user makes a request, it will first go to Spring's DispatcherServlet. The DispatcherServlet job is to send the request to spring mvc controller (custom controller)
2. You can define your custom controller like this:

**Controller: (code snippet)**

```
package nl.springexamples.mvc;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 /**
  * Handles requests for the application home page.
  */
 @Controller
 public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

3. In servlet- context file , mention the directory/package path of your controller.

   Example: `<context:component-scan base-package="nl.springexamples.mvc"/>`
4. In the above controller, it is returning string 'test' which is name of the view file(usually, it will be jsp).

JSP File: **test.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to Spring!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

5. Define this logical mapping of string name to view file in servlet-context like this:

Example: How to define internalViewResolver is as shown below

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the       /WEB-INF/views directory -->

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<beans:property name="prefix" value ="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

I think, that's pretty much about spring mvc and it's routing flow. I hope it helped you.